# Error - Please add NgModule annotation after using rxjs-compact

Tags: angular

After installing `npm install --save rxjs-compat` ,

I got an error in Angular 6 application

**Error:**

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'Observable' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021)
```

my app module --

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      ValueComponent,
      NavComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      FormsModule,
      Observable,
      Subject
    ],
```

package.json---
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you show us your app.module.ts code please.

Comment: you should not import `Observable, Subject ` in modules

Answer (score 0):

Like Omurbek Kadyrbekov mentioned in comment, you should not import rxjs into your modules.

In components, try exact import:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

instead of your

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: yeah i tried it but it didn't worked for me.it says- All imports in import declaration are unused.

Comment: According to https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/2577, please provide whole error line. Do you really use all imported things?